# Can't trigger parameter function that only runs on "yes" confirmation of a confirmation service that is using a Subject observable

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So I currently doing some unit tests for an Angular application using Jasmine and Karma. I'm having a problem with a unit test that must open a modal, and remove an item from a tree node.

Everything works fine until it reaches the `removeItem()` function. This removal process uses a `confirmationDialogService` as follows so the user can confirm the removal of the item:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfirmDialogService {
  subject = new Subject<any>();

  confirmThis(message: string, yesFn: () => void): any {
    this.setConfirmation(message, yesFn);
  }

  setConfirmation(message: string, yesFn: () => void): any {
    const that = this;
    this.subject.next({
      type: 'confirm',
      text: message,
      yesFn(): any {
        that.subject.next(); // This will close the modal
        yesFn();
      }
    });
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

And this is my .ts functions:

```
  openModalInternal(itemRootNode: SiteTreeNode, detectChanges: Function) {
    this.title = this.editMode ? 'Edit Item' : 'Add Item';
    const ngbModalOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
      ariaLabelledBy: this.title,
      backdrop: 'static',
      scrollable: true,
      size: 'xl',
      centered: true,
      keyboard: false
    };
    this.modalService.open(this.requestTypeItemTypeModal, ngbModalOptions).result.then(result => {
      if (result === 'Save') {
        this.saveItem(itemRootNode, detectChanges);
      } else if (result === 'Remove') {
        this.removeItem(itemRootNode, detectChanges);
      } else {
        this.clearFields();
      }
    });
  }

 removeItem(itemRootNode: SiteTreeNode, detectChanges: Function) {
        const removeMessage = this.defaultDropdownVisible
          ? 'Okay to permanetly delete the item and all its Drop Down Options?'
          : 'Okay to permanetly delete the item?';
        const requestTypeItemTypeId = this.requestTypeItemId;
        this.confirmDialogService.confirmThis(removeMessage, () => {
          const index = itemRootNode.childs.findIndex(x => x.id === requestTypeItemTypeId);
          this.siteService.deleteRequestTypeItem(requestTypeItemTypeId).subscribe(() => {
            // Can't reach the following code
            itemRootNode.childs.splice(index, 1);
            detectChanges();
            this.alertMessageService.setSuccessMessage([SuccessMessage.ItemRemovedMessage]);
          });
        });
        this.clearFields();
      }
```

The **problem** is that when the test reaches `this.confirmDialogService.confirmThis(...)` the second parameter of this, is a function that will be executed after the confirmation is true (user wants to remove item). This function is the `yesFn()` that the `confirmationDialogService` has. Inside this function there are some other functions that I want to spy On and expect things (like `deleteRequestTypeItem()`) but I cannot find a way to trigger this confirmation and this parameter function ( `yesFn()` ).

This is my .spec test

```
it('should remove item from tree node and show success message', fakeAsync(() => {
    const mockOpenModalResult = {
      result: new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve('Remove'))
    };
    
    spyOn(ngbModal, 'open').and.returnValue(mockOpenModalResult);
    spyOn(component, 'removeItem').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(confirmDialogService, 'confirmThis').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(confirmDialogService, 'setConfirmation').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(confirmDialogService.subject, 'next').and.returnValue(confirmDialogService.subject.asObservable());
    spyOn(siteService, 'deleteRequestTypeItem');
    confirmDialogService.subject.next();
    component.openModalInternal(mockItemRootNode, mockDetectChanges);
    flush();

    expect(component.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockItemRootNode, mockDetectChanges);
    expect(confirmDialogService.confirmThis).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(siteService.deleteRequestTypeItem).toHaveBeenCalled();

  }));
```

**Note:** Note that this uses a Subject observable in the confirmation service so there must be away to play with this in order to achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't reach there because you're spying on `deleteRequestTypeItem` and not returning a value. You're stubbing it as undefined.

Try this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
it('should remove item from tree node and show success message', fakeAsync(() => {
    const mockOpenModalResult = {
      result: new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve('Remove'))
    };
    
    spyOn(ngbModal, 'open').and.returnValue(mockOpenModalResult);
    spyOn(component, 'removeItem').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(confirmDialogService, 'confirmThis').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(confirmDialogService, 'setConfirmation').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(confirmDialogService.subject, 'next').and.returnValue(confirmDialogService.subject.asObservable());
    // !! - change this line - !!
    spyOn(siteMaintenanceService, 'deleteRequestTypeItem').and.returnValue(of({}));
    confirmDialogService.subject.next();
    component.openModalInternal(mockItemRootNode, mockDetectChanges);
    flush();

    expect(component.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockItemRootNode, mockDetectChanges);
    expect(confirmDialogService.confirmThis).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(siteService.deleteRequestTypeItem).toHaveBeenCalled();

  }));
```